# how to get the numbers of currently healthy running pods

Tags: kubernetes

I am searching for a way to get the numbers of currently healthy running pods, with this command:

```
kubectl get hpa -o=jsonpath='{.items[0].status.currentReplicas}'
```

I get the count of all pods regardless of whether the pod is running healthy or for example a pod has Insufficient CPU.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need the running pods, you can do this:

`kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Running`

If what you want is the **number**, like integer number of running pods, you can add:

`kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Running --no-headers=true | wc -l`

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much its, well, pointless. In case of `Insufficient CPU`, if its default limits for node or limits described in `spec.resources`, the pod is going to be terminated. You can request CPU consumption from the pod, and implement your own logic behind this, but what for?

```
# Current running pods and their last status
k get pods -o json | \ 
   jq '.items[] | { name:.metadata.name, status: .status.conditions[-1].type }'
```

Request you have in your question if returning the current replicas count of the pod auto scaler, and it's already tracking `currentMetricValue` to `desiredMetricValue` ratio. No need to tracked separately.